# Regex to check indonesian format number

Tags: java, regex

I try to check Indonesian format number using java regex. But i have some problem to do it. The problem is my regex can't detect 0,12 and 2.005.000 as a number(true).

**Below valid number in Indonesian format:** 
1  
15 
0,12  
123.621 
2.005.000

This is my code :

```
     Pattern doublePattern = Pattern.compile("[-+]?\\d*\\.?\\d+");
     System.out.println("1 is "+doublePattern.matcher("1").matches());
     System.out.println("15 is "+doublePattern.matcher("15").matches());
     System.out.println("0,12 is "+doublePattern.matcher("0,12").matches());
     System.out.println("123.621 is "+doublePattern.matcher("123.621").matches());
     System.out.println("2.005.000 is "+doublePattern.matcher("2.005.000").matches());
```

**Result/output program :**
1 is true 
15 is true 
0,12 is **false** 
123.621 is true 
2.005.000 is **false**

0,12 and 2.005.000 are false(not detect as number). i think my regex is wrong.

Comment: `How to make 0,12 and 2.005.000 become true?` Correct your regex.

Comment: What should be rejected by the regex, what's the context? Is `12345,2` ok? Is `[-+]?[\d.,]+` enough?

Comment: I'm glad you found an answer but be aware that it doesn't make sense to post only example input that should be validated by the regex, unless you want `.*` as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like this :

```
[-+]?[\d\.]*,?[\d\.]+
```

For a more visual comprehension you can put it in [regexper](http://www.regexper.com/#%5B-+%5D?%5B%5Cd%5C.%5D%2a,?%5B%5Cd%5C.%5D%2b) ;-)

Comment: You're welcome :-)

PS: mark this question as "answered" or you will be spammed with responses xD

Answer (score 1):

If the dot is mandatory for numbers greater than `999` you can use:

```
^[-+]?\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})*(?:,\d+)?$
```

`(?:\.\d{3})*` is a repeated non capturing group, accounting for the `.123` part in `4.123`.

`(?:,\d+)?` is the optional decimal part.

See [demo here](http://regex101.com/r/rW7nY1), don't forget to double escape for Java strings.

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
([-+]?\d([.,]\d)?)+
```